# Finding limit with approximation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I'm trying to find the limit of the following, where $m$ is a constant

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{2}\bigg(\frac{m}{n}\bigg)^{n}.$$

I start with using Stirling's approximation

$$(n-1)! \approx \sqrt{2\pi (n-1)}\bigg(\frac{n-1}{e}\bigg)^{(n-1)}$$

So I obtain

$$ \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} = (n-1)^{n-\frac12}e^{1-n}\bigg(\frac{m}{n}\bigg)^{n}$$

to which I can't see any simplification. Please suggest some hints. Thanks

Comment: seems like if $-1<m<1$ the sequence converge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

By Stirling's Approximation

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n!}{2n}\left(\dfrac{m}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{2n}\left(\dfrac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(\dfrac{m}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{2n}\left(\dfrac{m}{e}\right)^n$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: I obtain $\sqrt{2\pi}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n^.5}\bigg(\frac{m}{e}\bigg)^{n}$ which will equal 0 for $|m|<1$ ? This is not the result I was expecting.

Comment: @rodger_kicks Yes, as also shown on this [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0fpm3tkgsd).